# Ruby: How do I get the methods of a class without having an object of it?

Tags: ruby, reflection

"abc".respond_to?(:sub) returns true, but String.respond_to?(:sub) returns false.
The second returns false, because it asks whether objects of the class Class have a method sub, as String is an Object of Class. It is the same for methods()…

How do I do these things and especialy respond_to?() without creating an Object of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to confirm whether a method exists, `String.method_defined? :sub` will work.  If you are specifically interested in instance methods, use something like:

```
String.instance_methods.index 'sub'
```

Note that you have to use a string, not a symbol.

Comment: Array#include? is more intention-revealing than Array#index.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `method_defined?` method, declared in `Module` class.